# Disable mobile autosuggestion for input with "name" placeholder

Tags: html, ios, safari, placeholder, autosuggest

I have some text input with placeholder which contains word **"name"** - this causes iOS (Safari) to display autosuggestion panel (fill contact). How can I tell browser to not show any suggestions?

Autocomplete = "off" doesn't work.

Example code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Sth sth name" autocomplete="off" />
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ubn2g5vo/

If I remove **"name"** word from placeholder, autosuggestion panel doesn't show up, but I want to keep placeholder the way it is.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this would work or not but what if you wrote "name" in ascii? `<input type="text" placeholder="Sth sth &#110;&#97;&#109;&#101;" autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: It's impossible. I use Vue which escapes entities and I can't use v-html directive.